# Как в цикле Jade поставить условие?

Tags: html, jade

Привет! Как правильно в цикле прописать появление +e.block, т.е. если допустим я пропишу +breadcrumb('Один', 'Два') у меня только после первого item добавился +e.block.

```
mixin breadcrumb(...items)
// BEGIN section.b-breadcrumb
+b('ul').breadcrumb&attributes(attributes)
    each item in items
        +e('li').item
            +e('a')(href="#" title=item).link= item
        if item > 1
            +e('li').item--after-dot
                +e('a')(href="#" title=item).link= item
            +e.block
            +e('li').item--before-dot
                +e('a')(href="#" title=item).link= item
// END section.b-breadcrumb
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В each можно получить и индекс итерации:

```
each item, index in items
    +e('li').item
        +e('a')(href="#" title=item).link= item
    if index > 0
        +e('li').item--after-dot
            +e('a')(href="#" title=item).link= item
        +e.block
        +e('li').item--before-dot
```

Comment: только создает почему то 3 li теперь. Получается: Один, Два, Два

Comment: Это уже у вас в логике скрипта проблема. Видимо, нужно вывод e('li').item тоже обернуть в проверку, что это _первая_ итерация.

Comment: спасибо! буду пробовать тогда дальше.